# how to make mobile compatible website

Tags: mobile, web

i m trying to make a website that should be compatible with iphones, android devices etc. i need the help of experts here so that i can proceed further. please give me some idea about it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at jQuery Mobile:

http://jquerymobile.com/

and Phonegap:

http://www.phonegap.com/

Good luck with Blackberry though!

Answer (score 0):

Try with **bootstrap** :

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

It's easy to understanding and provide no. of extensions for creating responsive web templates.